# Can PVP be disabled in Minecraft for Xbox 360?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

How can I disable PVP in Minecraft for Xbox 360?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of the current version (available Jul 8 '12), you cannot disable PVP (being able to hurt each other). Maybe in future updates they will change that and maybe even allow more server options like the PC version. Sorry that this is not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: Argh, alright, thanks. It's especially annoying, considering you can even "hit" someone without facing them. Mining becomes a dangerous experience.

Comment: Yes, yes it does. I feel ya

Comment: This is outdated and incorrect.

Comment: @Nick, please do not edit somebody elses answer if you are going to completely re-write it. Post your own answer. Edits must keep the authors intent, regardless of if they are right, wrong, or outdated.

Answer (score 3):

As of now you can, when you create or load a world, you can disable PVP, if you click **options** before you load the game, you can **Toggle PVP on/off**

Answer (score 2):

There is an option called Trust Players. When disabled, this allows you to chose what ever your friend is allowed to do. One of the options is to attack players. To start, press back and activate your friend and chose the privalage can attack players.